# Creating TQReport elements at run time

Tags: delphi

Creating TQReport elements at run time.

Well, at least trying...

I don't know what headings or data shall appear on this report. I get a TList of TStrings representing the data rows and columns. I plant the 'Create' directives in the band print event for the group and the OnNeedData event for main data row bands.
But nothing appears. Must I make the labels at design time? Do not want.

Comment: Prepare the report at runtime, but before you call Print.

Comment: If you create components in code you have to assign theyr `Parent` property in order for them to show up. Might be similar case here, ie you have to assign band's and label's Parent property (or equal, I don't use QR myself so I'm not quite sure how it works).

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, this works:

```
// uses QuickRpt, qrpBaseCtrls, QRCtrls, QRPrntr;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var QR: TQuickRep;
    QB: TQRBand;
    QL: TQRLabel;
begin
  QR := TQuickRep.Create(Self);
  try
    QR.PrintIfEmpty := True;

    QB := TQRBand.Create(Self);
    QB.Parent := QR;
    QB.BandType := rbTitle;

    QL := TQRLabel.Create(Self);
    QL.Parent := QB;
    QL.Left := 10;
    QL.Top := 10;
    QL.AutoSize := True;
    QL.Caption := 'This works';

    QR.Preview;

  finally QR.Free;
  end;
end;
```