# Create childband Delphi (QR) at runtime

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I have the following code

```
procedure Tar_ardemo.qr_ardemoBeforePrint(Sender: TCustomQuickRep;
  var PrintReport: Boolean);
var
    QR: TquickRep;
    QB2: TQRBand;
    QB3: TQRChildBand;
    QL: TQRLabel;
begin
  with artikste do
  begin
    close;
    sql.Clear;
    sql.add('SELECT * FROM Artikels');
    open;
    first;
  end;

  QR := qr_ardemo;
  QB2 := QRBAND2;
  QB3 := TQRchildband.Create(QR);
  QB3.ParentBand := QB2;
  QB3.Height := 40;

  QL := TQRLabel.Create(QR);
  QL.Parent := QB3;
  QL.Left := 300;
  QL.Top := 1;
  QL.Width := 81;
  QL.Height := 23;
  QL.Caption := 'QRLabeZZ';
end;
```

I want to create a Childband (QB3) and a QRLabel (QL) at runtime. I just can't see it in my output, when I run the script in Delphi. When I change QL.Parent := QB3 to QB2, I see the output in QRBand2, but I want to see it in the just created Childband QB3. What do I wrong? I can not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that what you are trying is not possible. You can create the band at design time and use its BeforePrint event and set the Printband variable to false if you don't want to show the band.

Comment: I think it can see this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463182/creating-tqreport-elements-at-run-time. But its just the childband that gives the problem in my example

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
procedure Tar_ardemo.qr_ardemoBeforePrint(Sender: TCustomQuickRep;
  var PrintReport: Boolean);
var
    QR: TquickRep;
    QB2: TQRBand;
    QB3: TQRChildBand;
    QL: TQRLabel;
    QS : string;
begin
  with artikste do
  begin
    close;
    sql.Clear;
    sql.add('SELECT * FROM Artikels');
    open;
    first;
  end;

  QR := QR_ARDEMO;
  QB2 := QRBAND2;

  QB2.HasChild := true;
  QB2.ChildBand.Height := 23;
  QL := TQRLabel.Create(QR);
  QL.Parent := QB2.ChildBand;
  QL.Left := 100;
  QL.Top := 1;
  QL.Width := 81;
  QL.Height := 23;
  QL.Caption := 'QRLabeXX';

  QB2.ChildBand.HasChild := true;
  QB2.ChildBand.ChildBand.Height := 23;
  QL := TQRLabel.Create(QR);
  QL.Parent := QB2.ChildBand.ChildBand;
  QL.Left := 100;
  QL.Top := 1;
  QL.Width := 81;
  QL.Height := 23;
  QL.Caption := 'QRLabeYY';

  QB2.ChildBand.ChildBand.HasChild := true;
  QB2.ChildBand.ChildBand.ChildBand.Height := 23;
  QL := TQRLabel.Create(QR);
  QL.Parent := QB2.ChildBand.ChildBand.ChildBand;
  QL.Left := 100;
  QL.Top := 1;
  QL.Width := 81;
  QL.Height := 23;
  QL.Caption := 'QRLabeZZ';
end;

end.
```

This works (huray). But now the problem is: How do I get an array of childband.chhildband......childband. There is no Childband array like Childband[x]. Or is there one?? As I wrote there could be many Childbands [n]. It has to be dynamic, and... after printing the first childbands, they must be destroyed, before printing the next childbands for the next record (Artikel).

Comment: How can I use a string in a tqrband or childband?.

Comment: Hi Hans, this is a Q&A site so there are specific rules what you can post. as you said you solved it, you are free to post the correct answer to your question yourself and accept it so that it can help future visitors (and get upvotes).